# LaTeX with overleaf editor - my text goes off the page - how do I get it to go onto the next line, in line with my other text?

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am new to coding - I am using a template to create my CV with overleaf/LaTeX. There were some default settings but I wanted to create some elements that weren't in the default template. I am trying to add in headings within one of my job experiences but my text goes off the page - how do I get it to go onto the next line and stay in line with my other text?

[Screenshot of line going off the page][1]

```
%-------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author : Jake Gutierrez
% Based off of: https://github.com/sb2nov/resume
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage{ulem}
\input{glyphtounicode}


%----------FONT OPTIONS----------
% sans-serif
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{noto-sans}
% \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

% serif
% \usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
% \usepackage{charter}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

% Ensure that generate pdf is machine readable/ATS parsable
\pdfgentounicode=1

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{
  \item\small{
    {#1 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubSubheading}[2]{
    \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \text{#1} & #2 \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \small#1 & #2 \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}


\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{3pt}
\contourlength{0.8pt}

\newcommand{\myuline}[1]{%
  \uline{\phantom{#1}}%
  \llap{\contour{white}{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[1]{\resumeItem{#1}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand\labelitemii{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  RESUME STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING----------
% \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
%   \textbf{\href{http://sourabhbajaj.com/}{\Large Sourabh Bajaj}} & Email : \href{mailto:sourabh@sourabhbajaj.com}{sourabh@sourabhbajaj.com}\\
%   \href{http://sourabhbajaj.com/}{http://www.sourabhbajaj.com} & Mobile : +1-123-456-7890 \\
% \end{tabular*}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Huge \scshape *******} \\ \vspace{1pt}
    \small  $|$ \href{}{{}} $|$ 
    \href{}{\underline{LinkedIn}} 
\end{center}

%-----------EXPERIENCE-----------
\section{Experience}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart

    \resumeSubheading
      {}{}
      {}{}
     \linebreak
      \resumeItemListStart
      
        \resumeItem{}
        \resumeItem{}
        \resumeItem{}
        \linebreak
    
%        \resumeItem{\textbf{\underline{{Client: }}}}
%             \begin{enumerate}
%                  \item [-] 
%                 \item[-] 
%             \end{enumerate}
    
%        \resumeItem{\underline{}}
%             \begin{enumerate}
%                  \item [-] 
%                  \item [-]
%                  \item[-] 
%             \end{enumerate}
              

               \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0in, label={}]
    \small{\item{
     \text{\uline{}
     \item[-]{}
     \item[-]{}
     \end{enumerate}
    }}
 \end{itemize}           
             
     
             \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0in, label={}]
    \small{\item{
     \text{\uline{{}}} \\
     \begin{enumerate}
         \item[-]{.}
     \end{enumerate}
    }}
 \end{itemize}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz i have included the smallest bit of code possible

Comment: That's the problem. It is too small. It does not tell us what class you use, what packages are necessary to compile your code, doesn't have a document environment ...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have edited the code in the post. Sorry I am very new to all of this. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems:

- the syntax `\small{....}` is wrong. `\small` is a switch, which does not take an argument, so it should be `{\small ...}`. To avoid incorrect baselineskips, I suggest to place this outside of the `itemize` environment
- `\text{...}` is a math only command. You must not use it outside of math environments.
- `\item` does not take an mandatory argument. Instead of `\item{...}` it should be `\item ....`
- don't abuse `\\` for line breaks (outside of tables etc.).
- several missing `\end{itemize}`
- missing `\end{document}`

```
%-------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author : Jake Gutierrez
% Based off of: https://github.com/sb2nov/resume
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage{ulem}
\input{glyphtounicode}


%----------FONT OPTIONS----------
% sans-serif
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
% \usepackage[sfdefault]{noto-sans}
% \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

% serif
% \usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
% \usepackage{charter}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

% Ensure that generate pdf is machine readable/ATS parsable
\pdfgentounicode=1

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[1]{
  \item\small{
    {#1 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubSubheading}[2]{
    \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \text{#1} & #2 \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeProjectHeading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \small#1 & #2 \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}


\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{3pt}
\contourlength{0.8pt}

\newcommand{\myuline}[1]{%
  \uline{\phantom{#1}}%
  \llap{\contour{white}{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[1]{\resumeItem{#1}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand\labelitemii{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  RESUME STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING----------
% \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
%   \textbf{\href{http://sourabhbajaj.com/}{\Large Sourabh Bajaj}} & Email : \href{mailto:sourabh@sourabhbajaj.com}{sourabh@sourabhbajaj.com}\\
%   \href{http://sourabhbajaj.com/}{http://www.sourabhbajaj.com} & Mobile : +1-123-456-7890 \\
% \end{tabular*}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Huge \scshape Sophie Clarke} \\ \vspace{1pt}
    \small 07920 429 244 $|$ \href{sophieclarke@hotmail.co.uk}{{sophieclarke@hotmail.co.uk}} $|$ 
    \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/sophie-clarke-5b51aaba/}{\underline{LinkedIn}} 
\end{center}

%-----------EXPERIENCE-----------
\section{Experience}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart

    \resumeSubheading
      {Research Assistant in the Economics of International Trade}{September 2021 -- Present}
      {The UK Trade Policy Observatory}{Brighton, UK/ Remote}
     \linebreak
      \resumeItemListStart
      
        \resumeItem{Assist the UKTPO team of researchers with regard to data and background research and contribute to the production of research outputs for publication.}
        \resumeItem{Structure day-to-day research activities; prioritise and meet deadlines across multiple projects.}
        \resumeItem{Handle confidential information with diligence and circumspection.}
        \linebreak
    
%        \resumeItem{\textbf{\underline{{Client: British Chamber of Commerce}}}}
%             \begin{enumerate}
%                  \item [-] Used MATLAB to support the development of an analytical model to analyse answers to the BCC’s Quarterly Economic Survey using natural language processing, machine learning techniques and sentiment analysis.
%                 \item[-] Produced a final written report explaining methods, techniques, results and findings.
%             \end{enumerate}
    
%        \resumeItem{\underline{Ongoing Research Project: The Consequences of Brexit for the UK}}
%             \begin{enumerate}
%                  \item [-] Textual analysis of EU legal directives and regulations applicable to the single market.
%                  \item [-]Extensive preparation and use of data.
%                  \item[-] Written contribution to briefing paper publication.
%             \end{enumerate}
              
{\small
               \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0in, label={}]
    \item
     \uline{Client: British Chamber of Commerce} 
     \begin{enumerate}
     \item[-] Used MATLAB to support the development of an analytical model to analyse answers to the BCC’s Quarterly Economic Survey using natural language processing, machine learning techniques and sentiment analysis.
     \item[-] Produced a final written report explaining methods, techniques, results and findings.
     \end{enumerate}
 \end{itemize}  
 }         
             
    {\small 
             \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0in, label={}]
    \item
     \uline{Ongoing Research Project: The Impact of the UK Points Based System on European Union Professional Footballer Mobility in England} 
     \begin{enumerate}
         \item[-] Used MATLAB to support the development of a web scraping tool to gather primary data for the project.
     \end{enumerate}
 \end{itemize}
 }
 
 \end{itemize}
 \end{itemize}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much you have been really helpful